# Integrate Google Maps API into an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps

Update:  iPhone SDk 3.0 now addresses the question here, however the NDA prevents any in depth discussion.  Log in to the iPhone Dev Center if you need more info.

Ok, I have to admit I'm a little lost here.

I am fairly comfortable with Cocoa, but am having trouble picking up the bit of javascript needed to solve this problem.

I am trying to send a request to Google for a reverse geo code.

I have looked over the Google documentation I have viewed here:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/index.html
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Even after a rough reading, I am missing a basic concept:

How do I talk to google?  In some examples, they show a url being sent to google (which seems easy enough), but in others they show javascript.  It seems for reverse geocoding, the request might be be harder than sending the url with some parameters (but I hope I am wrong).

Can someone point me to the correct way to make a request?  (In objective-C, so I can wrap my head around it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UPDATE - iPhone 0.3 includes MapKit, which will hopefully be significantly faster than using the JS API. The blurb says that it will include reverse geocoding.

You can't make a request directly in objective-C, at least not within the terms of the Google API. The Google API is written in Javascript. You could use an objective-c to JS bridge, as the [Google Maps Component](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-google-maps-component/) does, but that doesn't really solve the issue - you're still making JS calls!

Unfortunately, that means you
a) need to use a webview
b) need to use the JS API which is slow... compare with the Google Maps application which uses a completely different OTA protocol (try packet sniffing it).

The Google Maps Component is, however, a useful tutorial in how to make simple calls to the API.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed like it was something like tedious that. Confirms my fears, as I only want to reverse geocode an address.  Seems like that would be trivial.

Answer (score 4):

I have created [SVGeocoder](https://github.com/samvermette/SVGeocoder), a simple forward **and** reverse geocoder class for iOS. It uses the Google Geocoding API, returns SVPlacemark objects (an `MKPlacemark` subclass with a `coordinate` property) and uses blocks.

This is how you geocode an address string:

```
[SVGeocoder geocode:addressString
         completion:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
             // do something with placemarks, handle errors
         }];
```

You can also reverse geocode a coordinate like this:

```
[SVGeocoder reverseGeocode:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.53264, -73.60518)
                completion:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                    // do something with placemarks, handle errors
                }];
```

Comment: I appreciate the "SVGeocoder" you have created. It works well except six blue warnings after analyzing. Three blue warnings in "SVGeocoder.m": 1)Potential leak of an object allocated on line 135:     self.request = ... 2)Potential leak of an object allocated on line 211: self.responseData = ... 3)Potential leak of an object allocated on line 214: self.connection = ... And Three blue warnings in "JSONKit.m", 1)Dead code on line 744: anObject = [anObject retain]; 2) Dead code on line 791: anObject = [anObject retain]; 3)Logic error on line 865: encodeState->serializeOptionFlags = optionFlags;

Comment: You should be posting that kind of stuff on GitHub, not in a SO comment.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get a Google map using Cocoa is to use the "Static Maps API". In practice, you need to prepare an NSURL that you use to contact Google. You get back your map as NSData, that you transform to an NSImage. Note that you can do both geocoding and reverse geocoding. You can also embed markers on the map. However, you loose the full controls you have access to if you use their JavaScript API.

Take a look at their reference guide here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Answer (score 2):

Now that apple have release the MapKit API for OS 3.0, I think your question has been answered.  Having looked at the API docs, I can see a heck of a lot of potential!  I still would like to see reverse geocoding webservice from Google, but Yahoo will do in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

For your information: The reverse geocoding API from Google for requests by XML isn't public, so it's illegal to use. The only legal way is going through their JavaScript-API, which as you found out is harder to do in Cocoa than to simply send an HTTP request.

Alternatives: Reverse geocoding with simple XML/JSON requests is also available from [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/maps/reverse-geocoder.html#findNearestAddress) or [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS5 we have the following options as stated in the development doc:
* "A geocoder object uses a network service to convert between latitude and longitude values and a user-friendly placemark, which is a collection of data such as the street, city, state, and country information. Reverse geocoding is the process of converting a latitude and longitude into a placemark. Forward geocoding is the process of converting place name information into a latitude and longitude value. Reverse geocoding is supported in all versions of iOS but forward geocoding is supported only in iOS 5.0 and later."*

You can now use a CLGeocoder object.

Answer (score 0):

Also try to take a look at [google maps component](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-google-maps-component/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I did not meant reverse geocoding as "translating a point into a human-readable address", but rather visualizing a point using a Google Map (that can also, depending on the accuracy level, show a  human-readable address). This is the basic functionality that was required.

In practice, I just wanted to suggest the static maps API as a clean and fast way to:

1) given the coordinates obtained from the iPhone GPS sensor, retrieve a Google Map showing  the point

2) given an address, transform it in the corresponding geographical coordinates and then use  the coords to retrieve a Google Map showing the address given

Both are possible using simple NSURLs involving the staticmap and geo services

http://maps.google.com/staticmap?
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?

passing of course the needed parameters to provide a suitable query string.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

The big issue of course, is that the license agreement of both google and yahoo state you can't use these API's in "commercial applications". would hate to pub an app on the app store only to have it taken down and sued by yahoo or google. In reading the iPhone 3.0 map api and associated license this isn't mentioned but if you want an app to run on phones not upgraded....

Is there an answer for this that won't get one in trouble?

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.cloudmade.com/2009/06/12/how-to-get-forward-geocoding-in-iphone-mapkit/

CloudMade seems to be an open-source map/location provider - the above blog post lists details on how to get forward geocoding.