# Using Google Map in iPhone App development - License Required or not?

Tags: google-maps

I need to integrate Google Map Api in to my iphone App.

Do we need to get licence on using Google Map in our iPhone App development?

Many thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Mahesh.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to sign up for, and agree with the TOS associated with the Google Map API in order to utilize it in your application.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/

Answer (score 0):

Also see these questions:

- [Do commercial (paid) iPhone apps have to pay a license to Google for Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444678/)
- [Integrate Google Maps API into an iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551886/)